# VSTS REST API not accepting POST request

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I'm trying to use VSTS's REST API to create a new file in a repository. I've used Microsoft's documentation, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pushes#add-a-text-file, but I keep getting an error saying the following:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.

Here's the request I'm sending to the API:

```
POST https://company.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project_ID/_apis/git/repositories/repository_ID/pushes?api-version=1.0
```

My credentials are properly configured, as it's getting to the resource (using basic authentication with a PAT). The project and repo ID were gathered using a similar GET request, which worked fine.
I've tested this request using POSTMAN, and it blurts out the error mentioned above. I've made sure to configure the header as `application/json`, but it does nothing.

Also tried different versions of the API, always the same error.

Is there something I'm missing ? The documentation clearly states that this should work using POST, so I'm really confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the `project_ID` should not be included in the URL.

Just try below REST API:

```
POST https://company.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories/{repository ID}/pushes?api-version=4.1-preview.2

Content-Type: application/json

{"refUpdates":[{"name":"refs/heads/Dev","oldObjectId":"53e349753ff5a081346babe32255eb6c5da63a5a"}],"commits":[{"changes":[{"changeType":1,"item":{"path":"/test.txt"},"newContent":{"content":"123test","contentType":0}}],"comment":"Added file test.txt"}]}
```

***Note that you need to use the latest commit SHA as the `oldObjectId` every time to run it, otherwise it will response `409 Conflict` error.***

Follow below steps to get the latest commit SHA:

1. Go to the **Code** page > **Files**
2. Choose a repository and branch
3. Select the root level (repository name) > **History**
4. Click **…** of the **first commit** > **Copy full SHA**

[image]

Comment: YES! This worked like a charm. Not having the latest API version was causing the POST issue. Changing the url to use 4.0 (I'd rather stay away from previews, simply because support will eventually go away) solved that issue. After changing the `oldObjectId` value, and using the correct branch, it worked like a charm!! Thanks again for your valuable help :)